# día por medio; mes por medio, semana por medio... are these used often for every other day, month or week?

Tags: gramática, significado-en-contexto

In my Mango online course they're teaching us "día por medio", and in my explorations on Linguee I see there's also a week and month version, meaning every other day, every other week, every other month.  I've also seen indications that format is used in Latin America and not in Spain.  Is it even used much in Latin America?  The context would be something like: "Me ducho día por medio". "I take a shower every other day".  When I translated backwards in Linguee it didn't give the same Spanish; instead "Me ducho cada dos días."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar a la locución del inglés ‘every other day’, **día por medio** significa ‘un día sí, el siguiente no, el siguiente del siguiente sí, ..., y así sucesivamente’. En símbolos: [..., Ocurre, No ocurre, Ocurre, No ocurre, ...]. Es decir, algo ocurre día por medio cuando ocurre cada dos días.

En la Argentina la expresión se usa, y mucho. Tengo entendido que en toda Hispanoamérica la expresión es de uso corriente. Otra variante es *día **de** por medio*, ambas son completamente válidas y reconocidas. En España se suelen usar otras expresiones, pero perfectamente pueden entender la expresión en cuestión.

Y sí: ‘mes por medio’, ‘semana por medio’, ‘año por medio’; todas tendrían el mismo significado pero son bastante más raras de escuchar porque el patrón se observa más a menudo en días que en semanas o meses. Dudo que suenen naturales a oídos de un nativo; yo en su lugar diría ‘cada dos meses’ o ‘cada dos semanas’.

Comment: Eso de "día de por medio" no es muy común en España. "Día sí, día no" o "cada dos días". Y eso de "semana por medio" o "mes por medio", ¿no es más fácil decir "quincenal" o "bimestral" respectivamente?

Comment: Y "día sí, día también", frase que a mi me resulta bastante llamativa.

Comment: @Danielillo Bueno, eso es como decir todos los días XD Quizás esa forma resalta un poco más la constancia. Como "un día, y otro, y otro, y otro" resaltaría la monotonía.

Comment: In English every other day does mean what you guessed it to mean. It is used more widely to mean alternate, not just for time periods.

Comment: @RubioRic Oka gracias ya lo edité. Y no, no es lo mismo decir ‘bimestral’, que ‘cada dos meses’. Un fenómeno puede ser bimestral y *extenderse como continuo* a lo largo de dos meses, que no es lo mismo que *esté discretizado y se repita* cada dos meses. Idem con ‘quincenal’, que además significa ‘quince días’ que no es lo mismo que ‘dos semanas’. Compará: ‘mi curso de matemática es bimestral’ vs ‘curso matemática mes por medio’. La segunda indica que tengo una clase cada dos meses, lo que carece de sentido.

Comment: El significado de bimestral depende del contexto, sirve tanto para cada dos meses (publicación bimestral) como que dura dos meses (asignatura bimestral). Lo de "curso matemática mes por medio" ni idea de donde lo has sacado ni qué significa.

Comment: Si un mes tiene unos treinta días, quincenal es dos veces al mes. Y pasa lo mismo que con bimestral. Puede ser cada 15 días o que dura 15 días.

Comment: @RubioRic Es cierto que en algunos casos el contexto permite que bimestral pueda interpretarse exclusivamente como ‘dura dos meses’, o bien ‘cada dos meses’, pero hay otros casos en los que va a prestarse a la ambigüedad. Por eso no creo que sea un equivalente exacto de ‘cada dos meses’. Por otra parte, quince días no son dos semanas, un poco de matemática no hace mal a nadie!

Comment: Ahora me pongo a estudiar, gracias por el consejo!

Comment: Me pondré hora por medio. Sea lo que sea eso

Answer (score 2):

**Día por medio** o **día de por medio** da a entender que es algo que ocurre de manera constante, excepto un día entre dos eventos. También puedes decir *con dos días de por medio*, *con una semana de por medio*, *con un mes de por medio*. Mi opinion es que este tipo de frases puede entenderse en todas las variantes de español aunque en algunas sonará raro.

En México la expresión *dia de por medio* no es muy común. Mas común es la expresión *un día si y un día no* que puede extenderse a semanas y meses. Otra expresión común es *cada tercer día* (que significa lo mismo que *cada dos dias*) y curiosamente solo funciona con dias.

Comment: no sería *con un día de por medio*? Y yo creo que la pronunciación es muy distinta de *día promedio*

Comment: @tac ¿La pronunciación de "día por medio" y "día promedio" es MUY distinta? Si tú no añades "un", ¿porqué debería añadirse aquí?

Comment: @RubioRic Primero: lo digo porque dijo con DOS días de por medio. Es con UN día de por medio. Segundo: estás muy equivocado, es diferente. Pero está bien, supongamos que acaso fuesen similares las pronunciaciones. Entonces no hay ninguna excusa para esquivarle a la expresión. Acostumbrarse a la pronunciación es parte del aprendizaje. Es como decir: nunca digas *beach* porque la pronunciación es similar a *b.tch*, cuando cualquier angloparlante sabe que son cosas bien distintas. No es excusa...

Comment: @RubioRic Y menos lo sería en el español, uno de los idiomas con la pronunciación más fácil del mundo. Además, dudo que ‘hago x actividad día *promedio*’ tenga algún sentido. Acaso no somos capaces de reconocer el contexto, ergo, discernir la palabra correcta?

Comment: Gracias por sus cometarios. Definitivamente, "día por medio" es correcto. También es cierto que un nativo difícilmente se va a confundir por el contexto de la conversación. Ademas, no me corresponde decirle a un hablante nativo que frase usar o cual no. El comentario estaba dirigido a alguien que estuviera arendiendo el español. Pero un estudiante de español no esta libre de escuchar esta frase así que el comentario carece de sentido y debido a esto edito mi respuesta.